# SQL: convert tokens in a string or elements of an array into rows of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a simple way in SQL to convert a string or an array to rows of a table?

For example, let's stay the string is 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'. I'd prefer an SQL statement that takes that string, splits it at commas and inserts the resulting strings into a table. In PostgreSQL I can use regexp_split_to_array() and split the string into an array. So, if you know a way to  insert an array's elements as rows into a table, that would work too.

Comment: Great answers and feedback. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn an array into a rowset, you can simply use [unnest()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT unnest('{1,2,3,4}'::int[])
```

Which you can then of course combine with regexp_split_to_array, to become:

```
SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array('1,2,3,4', ','))
```

or as previously mentioned, using string_to_array() instead of regexp_split_to_array() if it's a simple split.

Comment: Perhaps it's important to note that `unnest` exists from Postgres 8.4 and up.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `string_to_array` instead, it's a bit faster :)
Regardless though, you can create a `table` out of it with some `generate_series` tricks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_to_table(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$ 
SELECT $1[i] 
FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) g(i);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * FROM array_to_table(string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e,f,g', ','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate_series (FROM, TO, STEP) with (1, 7, 2) produces a series 1, 3, 5, 7 which can be used to index the array for substring (COLUMN, INDEX, LEN):

```
SELECT substring ('a,b,c,d', generate_series (1, 7, 2), 1) AS x ;
 x 
---
 a
 b
 c
 d
```